# how to redirect one subdomain to another without altering my java application

Tags: java, dns, redirect

I have a java application running on a linux machine using Tomcat. There are two DNS entries for this machine:

- abc.mycompany.com
- xyz.mycompany.com.

Both of these URLs work fine and are externally accessible. When user enters `xyz.mycompany.com`, I want that URL to redirect to `abc.mycompany.com`.

How can I achieve this without changing application code?

Answer (score 1):

If this is meant to **permanently** redirect xyz -> abc (I'm unclear from your question if this is the case or not) and you insist on doing this via DNS then you could simply go to your nameserver and modify your "mycompany" domain to forward the xyz.mycompany.com url to abc.mycompany.com. This is fairly easy and straightforward to do; add an `A record` for the `xyz host` and set the destination url to `abc.mycompany.com`.

Otherwise, you could do this through Apache instead using a `<Virtualhost>` with `RedirectPermanent` ([here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx) is a good tutorial from d.o.) or using a `.htaccess` file with `RewriteEngine` ([here](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/) is a good post to get you started).

Comment: The host machine for xyz and abc is same. xyz.mycompany.com and abc.mycompany.com point to the same server.

Comment: Yes, you'd mentioned that in your post. But wasn't clear if this was only an internal network redirect or external. If this is for external access, then adding a record on your nameserver will do the trick. If not, then internal DNS will be required and we can go from there.

Comment: This is for external access. The application server is Tomcat. I believe there is no seperate web server in place.

Comment: can you tell me how exactly a record need to be added in the nameserver (DNS server) to achieve this redirection

Comment: I've more or less given you what you need. Login into your nameserver (godaddy, namecheap, bluehost, etc... whoever you purchased "mycompany.com" from). Manage your domain, find something along the lines of "host management" and find where you can add/change records or add simply url forwarding.